# Irish Short Stay visa waiver for Indian Citizen in the US

Tags: visas, usa, uk, indian-citizens, ireland

I am an Indian Citizen residing in the US. I have a valid short stay UK Tourist visa stamped in my Indian passport at the UK consulate in the US (No BIVS stamp), I am entering UK first and plan on travelling to Dublin. Do I need a separate visa?

The Irish government describes the short-stay visa waiver programme [on its website](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/inis/pages/irish+short+stay+visa+waiver+programme).

Comment: @Daniil careful with the edits, the OP has an Indian passport not an American one.

Comment: @Ozzy Thanks, I approved your edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Breaking it down for you from your [link](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/inis/pages/irish+short+stay+visa+waiver+programme):

> - Do you have an eligible UK short stay visa?

Yes you do

> - Does your visit to Ireland end before your permission to stay in UK ends (this is granted by an UK immigration official when you pass through UK immigration)?

You don't yet have this information, but let's assume they grant you the stay as you planned. So, yes.

> - Was your passport issued by one of the countries listed in the list below?

India is listed, so yes.

By all indications from the official website to which you have also linked, you are indeed able to do this with the UK visa without additional need for an Ireland visa.

This is also supported by the [following](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/visa-short-tourist):

> Travel between Ireland & UK using a single UK-Irish visa
>
> You can visit Ireland and the United Kingdom using a single visa issued by either country, if you are a Chinese or Indian citizen. For instance:
>
> You can visit the UK (including Northern Ireland) without applying for a UK visa, if you have an Irish Visit (Tourist) Visa.
> You can visit Ireland without applying for an Irish visa, if you have an eligible UK (short stay) visitor visa.
> You can travel an unlimited number of times between each country with either visa, for as long as it is valid.
>
> Read how this works under the [British-Irish Visa Scheme](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/British%20Irish%20Visa%20Scheme).

Comment: Thank you for a quick reply, your reply definitely give me some confidence that I should be fine. I am eligible to go Ireland under short stay visa waiver program but not under British-Irish Visa Scheme as that requires BIVS endorsement on visa stamped. Which I think you only get if applied in Indian or Chinese visa offices.

Comment: With respect to "this is also supported by the following": that applies only to visas that are explicitly marked BIVS, which the question informs us is not the case.

Comment: @Bringiton you are correct: BIVS visas [are only issued in India and China](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/british-irish-visa-scheme/british-irish-visa-scheme), at least currently (the linked page says "during the first phase of the scheme").